# Where does the golden great ape transformation fit in the saiyan transformations scale?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-gt, dragon-ball-heroes

Are the multipliers from the super saiyan transformation (x50) and Oozaru transformation (x10) supposed to add up in the golden great ape transformation? 
Or does it have just a different multiplier? With x10 (Oozaru) *x50 (SSJ) it would be x500 which is little over SSJ3 (x400) , but if I recall correctly Baby golden great ape transformation was a tough fight for SSJ4 Goku .

Where does the golden great ape transformation fit in the saiyan transformations scale? Is it over SSJ3? Is it equal to SSJ4? Is it over SSJ4?

Comment: Of course your assumption is correct, but it was not officially told and gloden great ape is on par with ssj4, but ssj4 Goku has difficulty because no matter how you look, at it is an over sized gorrila which doesn't have any control.so Goku had difficulty in handling it and also he must be concerned about Vegeta